# Upload an image to AWS S3 private bucket using presign url

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am facing a problem while uploading an image to **s3 private bucket** using nodejs aws sdk.
This is what I have done so far.

```
import aws from 'aws-sdk';
aws.config.update({
 signatureVersion: 'v4',
 region: 'ap-southeast-1',
 accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY,
 secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_S3_SECRET_KEY,
});

const s3 = new aws.S3();
export const generate_pre_ssigned_url_write = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    const { Key, ContentType } = req.query;
    const { userId } = req;
    const params = {
        Bucket: 'test-bucket',
        Key: `${userId}/${Key}`,
        Expires:200,
    };
    const preSignedUrl = await s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params);
    res.send({preSignedUrl});
}
catch(err){
 console.log(err);next(err);
}
}
```

1. I know by creating a bucket policy in my s3 bucket the image can be uploaded.
   currently, I am having the following bucket policy

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1592575147579",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1592575144175",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",// Thinking to 
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*",
            "Principal": "*" // here what must this value for aws ec2 instance which is present //in different region from s3 buckets region.
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1592575144176",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",// Thinking

            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*",
            "Principal": "*" // having a * here makes the bucket public which I don't want
        }

    ]
}
```

In the above policy,

1. For the first case, what must be the attribute **Principal** if I only want to **putObject** in the bucket from specific AWS EC2 instance **or** Is there any other way that I can insert objects into s3 bucket using pre-signed url.
2. For the second case, 
   If I have the **Principal** as * then the bucket is becoming public which is not desired, so I thought of writing a pre-signed URL similar to above javascript snippet like `s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params)`. But I have many images to show on front-end
   which will definitely increase the load on my server as each image will make presign URL request to the server, so I want to avoid this approach also. I would like to find out if there is any other approach to this?

Comment: You don't need a bucket policy at all. If the credentials that you used to pre-sign the PUT/POST URL have permission to put the object to that bucket, then that's sufficient.

Comment: ok, but I also need to GET the object, If I am trying to load the object in a browser by using the url of the object I am getting Access denied

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to make the bucket or the objects publicly readable so you need to authorize access to them. Typically your users would authenticate to your backend and then you would serve pages that contain pre-signed GET URLs for the images. There's no excess load on your server. Creating pre-signed URLs is a trivial, and fast, process. The files themselves are served from S3, not your web server.

Comment: I completely understand what you said, Thanks for that, so if I make the objects publicly readable, then I need to create a bucket policy for GetObject which has principal as *, so that I can completely avoid the above process of authorisation, right?

Comment: Or is there any way that I can add public read permissions while PUT the object itself?

Comment: Yes, assuming that it's OK for the objects to be publicly readable, you would do that with a bucket policy as you've indicated. There are numerous example of these policies available in the documentation, if needed.